# Find majority element from input

Tags: java, algorithm

Can i find majority element only reading input w/o adding to an array?
My code dont't work at big input, with large difference of numbers.

I find my mistake. There right code:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(bin.readLine()); // read number of data
int h = 0; //input data
int count = 1; //counter
int lf = 0; // last top counting
int first = 0; // top counter num

for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    lf = h;
    h = Integer.parseInt(bin.readLine());//read input number
    if (x == 0) {
        first = h;
    }
    if (h == first) {
        count++;
    } else {
        count--;
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        first = lf; 
        count = 1;
    }
```

Comment: What do you call a majority element? This code seems to count how many times the first element occurs in the input.

Comment: Your code should work regardless of the number of inputs. What do you mean by "dont't work"?

Comment: When i have input more of 100 000 numbers, it give wrong answer.

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Are you deliberately falling through from one if to another? (For example for the first element, first you set `first` to `h`, then increment `count`, then set it back to 1)

Comment: If the most common number is the second number, it'll give the wrong answer too. The only time it'll ever give the right answer is if the first number is the most common number. See Qnan's comment (first one).

Comment: I try realesate this algo - http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/index.html  w/o array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large input shouldn't cause any problems, you just assumed that's the problem when it failed on (a) large file(s?).

The code looks more-or-less OK, but IIRC you if the counter reaches zero, you have to pick (= set `first` to a new value) the *next* element, and not the previous one.